# How can I change the date in .bat batch files

Tags: batch-file

I have 50 batch files, those have same date like "04.2013" in the script.
Every month I am changing the date mannualy like "04.2013 to 05.2013" by editing each batch file.

Can I do it by one script? please help

I have below command in the batch files:
"set DateFolder=04.2013"

Comment: Take a search & replace tool, eg. `sed`.

Comment: The trouble with working with dates in batch is that the exact instructions depend on your computer's locale, as the date can only (natively) be returned as a string which you then have to parse.  Matt Williamson has given you a good answer to get you started.  Also see http://www.robvanderwoude.com/datetime.php for other ideas, including other utilities that can help avoid the locale dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method is to have a batch file called **DateFolder.bat** which contains

```
@set DateFolder=04.2013
```

and in every batch file include this before starting to use the variable

```
call DateFolder.bat
```

This assumes that all your batch files use the same variable - and you only need to adjust the DateFolder.bat in future.

Comment: @echo off
setlocal
set DateFolder=04.2013
set TargetFolder=C:\Documents and Settings\nk94\Desktop\test macro\Raw Files


:: copy the newest file from AccrualPnLMTD and rename it to AccrualMTD.csv
call :copyAndRename "C:\Documents and Settings\nk94\Desktop\test macro\PWMF\AccrualPnLMTD" "%TargetFolder%\AccrualMTD.csv"

Comment: :: Done
goto :eof



:copyAndRename
set SourceFolder=%~1
set TargetFile=%~2

:: Find the newest file in the source folder
for /f "tokens=*" %%F in ('dir /b /od /a-d "%SourceFolder%"') do set "NewestFile=%%F"

:: copy and rename it to the target
copy "%SourceFolder%\%NewestFile%" "%TargetFile%"

:: Done with this subroutine
goto :eof

Comment: foxidrive , this is my batchfile script. can you plz suggest where I can put the command "call DateFolder.bat"

Comment: Where you have set DateFolder=04.2013 replace that with call DateFolder.bat (after you have created DateFolder.bat on the path)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you replace your

```
 set datefolder=04.2013
```

and use the %date% variable to dynamically get the date. Depending on what your date format is you just need a little bit of code to pull out the month and year.

example:

```
 Date format: Fri 04/26/2013
```

the following code will extract the month and year

```
 for /f "tokens=2,4 delims=^/ " %%a in ('echo %date%') do (echo %%a.%%b)
```

Comment: Suppose this is only numbers then how can I change in each batch file. by creating only onc batch file : 04.2013 should change like 05.2013

Comment: You want to do a recursive search through all of your existing files and change 04.2013 to 05.2013?

Comment: yes, whichever batch file has 04.2013 should change 05.2013. that will work for me.