# How can I change the data in .bat batch files

Tags: batch-file

[How can I change the date in .bat batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238342/haw-can-i-change-the-date-in-bat-batch-files/16240263#16240263)

I have got my answer by  foxidrive for the above question. But I have once more concern abot this question.

When I am running my main script from that location where Datefolder.bat not saved, then It's not working. Can anyone please advice how can I define the location for the Datefolder.bat where it is saved. so, macro can call DateFolder.bat where it's saved.

Comment: Let me clear it more: I have two scripts on same location one is main and other is supporting, When i run the main script from same location "F:\MY DOCUMENTS" it's working but when I moov Datefolder.bat(supporting) script to diffrent locaton "C:\MY DOCUMENTS" it's not working. , so how can i difine the path of datefolder.bat in my main script. plz advice

Comment: Please provide the content of `datefolder.bat`. I can not guess today my crystal ball is cloudy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this sort of command where %userprofile% expands to your own profile.

```
call "%userprofile%\documents\datefolder.bat"
```

Or the full path (but double check the path for accuracy).

```
call "c:\users\niki niki\documents\datefolder.bat"
```

But if you are using the actual current date then the best way is to automate the extraction of the current date - and where you have put the `call datefolder.bat` you can put this in every batch file, and it will set the current MM-YYYY in the datefolder variable.  It uses Wmic which is available in XP pro and above I think.

```
:: timestamp MM-YYYY
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set datefolder=%dt:~4,2%-%dt:~0,4%
echo %datefolder%
```

Comment: thx foxi, now it's working by this command "call "c:\users\niki niki\documents\datefolder.bat"